# Selecting in HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to identify what text the user has selected in the web page??

Example: I want to build an application similar to online translation:

- The user is reading some html (provided to the user through my server)
- Then he/she selects a sentence in that page (asking for its translation)
- So the javascript should handle this event and send back to the server asking for the translation...

Any ideas how to know what text the user is currently selecting??

Comment: Due to send again information to server, i can suggest you tu use some Ajax?

Comment: sure.. but still need to identify the offset of the selected text...

Comment: Ok, just dind't understood the real essence of the question. So antyrat answer seems to be very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do that using [selection rage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection).

For example using [getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) method.